# How to use ilasm with "release"-mode

Tags: il, ilasm

I would like to use ilasm to compile il code. There are quite many parameters I can use. In visual studio I can simply tick "Optimize code" in the project settings. How can I enable the ilasm compiler to compile in "release"-mode, optimize the code and create as less as possible debug information -> I would like to achieve the best possible performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [command-line parameters for ilasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to affect the compilation. It sounds like you're after the `/optimize` parameter. However, this only does minor optimization; switching "long instructions" to shorter ones. It will affect the number of bytes required to encode the instruction, so it will save a few bytes for you.

Writing il code means that you know exactly how you want things done, and there will be no compile-time optimizations (except for the long-to-short instruction conversion).

You're probably more interested in the [jit-compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) (runtime conversion of il instructions to machine assembler), but there's not much you can do to it. It does what it does without external interference, and usually does it good.

Writing il code means that you give up the idea of having a high level language (like C#) that can express what you want in fewer lines of code, and let any cool tools you find analyze it for inlining, possible threading issues and see what can be executed in parallel on several cores. Writing il code means that you claim you know how to write better il code than the assembler. Do you?

Comment: I think that should be "[...] better il code than the compiler.", since the assembler stage still runs in both cases and shouldn't substantially touch the IL either way.

Comment: Well. I have to use instructions, the default compiler does not support. I've read about the `/debug` switch. But I don't really understand what it does. Is there anything I can do with that to optimize the performance?

Comment: “there's not much you can do to it” Well, you can disable it using the `/debug` switch.

Comment: Well my problem is, that I am afraid of that I don't understand the purpose of the /debug switch. Should I turn it off?

Comment: You want release-code, you shouldn't be touching the /debug switch at all. It's a switch which presence enables certain debugging features. A missing /debug switch means that it's turned off. You can use /pdb if you want to generate a pdb file to help with future debugging/stack traces.